# Using btouch to generate one binding assembly from multiple native library

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to use **[btouch](http://code.google.com/p/btouch-library/)** to generate one binding assembly from multiple native libraries? The goal being to reduce the number of assembly references used by my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Xamarin uses the same `btouch` tool to create monotouch.dll which contains bindings for several iOS frameworks.

It's also quite similar to `bmac` (shared sources with `btouch`) which is used to build bindings for MonoMac - again several frameworks bound in a single MonoMac.dll.

The scripts (Makefile) used for the second one are available publicly in [github](https://github.com/mono/monomac).